# How can a Scanner throw an exception during runtime?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

like what are the errors that can cause the Scanner to throw an exception?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: What are the ways you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner` can throw exceptions that are descendants of the `RuntimeException` class.

For example, there is a `NoSuchElementException` that is thrown when the `nextLine()` method is called and there is no next line. Please read the documentation for [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)